# Crawling Amazon

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a Python web crawler but for some reason when I try to crawl a website, like Amazon, the only thing my program prints out is 'None'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apython&page=' + str(page) + '&keywords=python&ie=UTF8&qid=1482022018&spIA=B01M63XMN1,B00WFP9S2E'
        source = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source.text
        obj = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html5lib")

        for link in obj.find_all('a'):
            href = link.get(url)
            print(href)
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried another more simple page? Some websites disallow web crawlers

Comment: What's a page I can try?

Comment: try https://thenewboston.com/. The creator of that site has a really in-depth python crawler tutorial as well if you're interested. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGA8Vys-f48mAH9OKSUyav0q) the YouTube playlist

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the header and the parameters in your request.
You can do the following steps to make the task simple:

1. Right-click on the site you want to crawl and select "inspect". (Google Chrome default)
2. Go to the "network" menu and right-click on the request you want to crawl.
3. Select "Copy as cURL".
4. Go to one of the converter sites like "https://curl.trillworks.com/" and get the Python code (or other languages) you want

Answer (score -1):

without User-Agent:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apython&page=1%20%27&keywords=python&ie=UTF8&qid=1482022018&spIA=B01M63XMN1,B00WFP9S2E%27
```

with User-Agent:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apython&page=1%20%27&keywords=python&ie=UTF8&qid=1482022018&spIA=B01M63XMN1,B00WFP9S2E%27', headers=headers)
```

it works fine.

[How to prevent getting blacklisted while scraping](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/) you can read this page to understand why you should use UA.

Comment: I think you should give an explanation instead of just telling OP what to do.

Comment: ^I second that.